Total number of (unique) moments of the Haar distribution
This is probably a standard fact but I cannot find it in my usual references. Let $G$ be one of the classic matrix Lie groups $\mathrm{U}(N), \mathrm{SU}(N), \mathrm{O}(N), \mathrm{SO}(N)$, equipped with the Haar measure $\mu$. One way to study the $t$-th moment of $\mu$ is by defining the matrix
$$\Phi^{(t)}_\mu = \int_G U^{\otimes t} \otimes (U^*)^{\otimes t} \, \mu(dU),$$
where $U^*$ is the entrywise complex conjugate of $U$. At what value of $t$ do we have a complete characterization of the distribution? For example, in the scalar setting, a Gaussian distribution over $\mathbb{R}$ is completely characterized by its first two moments.
I believe an equivalent way to phrase the question is also: given some normalized measure $\nu$ on $G$, what is the smallest $t$ such that $\Phi^{(t)}_\mu = \Phi^{(t)}_\nu$ iff $\mu = \nu$?

The two formulations given in your question are in fact not equivalent: While the normal/Gaussian distribution is determined by the first two moments, you still have to check all moments if you want to find out whether the distribution is Gaussian! (and infinitely many are non-zero).
As far as I know, the Gaussian setting is not simpler then the generic setting where you want to find out whether two probability measures are equal by looking at (all of) their moments. Note that given that all moments agree, there are still pathological cases when the measures do not, see Hamburger moment problem.
I think both questions are interesting, but I do not know a resolution to the first one: Are all moments of the Haar measure determined by the moments up to a finite $t$?
Thus, let me answer the second question instead:
Another way of looking at the "moment problem" is via characteristic functions, or in a more modern language, Fourier transforms of measures. For (finite Borel) measures $\nu$ on compact groups $G$, we can define a Fourier transform $\hat\nu$ by the collection of (finite-dimensional) operators, indexed by irreps $\tau$ of $G$:
$$
 \hat\nu(\tau) := \int_G \bar\tau(g) \,d\nu(g)\,.
$$
Then, one can show that the mapping $\nu\mapsto\hat\nu$ is an isomorphism on the Banach space of finite Borel measures on $G$ (into a slightly weird space though), and hence $\nu=\mu$ iff $\hat\nu=\hat\mu$. This is yet another version of a fundamental result in harmonic analysis, the Peter-Weyl theorem.
Since the compact groups you mentioned have infinitely many irreps, we have to check $\hat\nu=\hat\mu$ on all of these. Moreover any irrep is contained in $U^{\otimes t} \otimes \bar{U}^{\otimes t}$ for sufficiently high $t$, implying that is indeed not enough to check equality of your moment operators for finite $t$.
A side remark: For finite $t$, you would get a unitary $t$-design, and these can in general even by finite sets (i.e. counting measure on those).

Yes, perhaps my question was ill-posed, or at least phrased confusingly. While indeed there are an infinite number of moments to check, I am wondering if after a finite moment $t^\star$, all other $t>t^\star$ moments are dependent on the lower moments. In the Gaussian analogy, this is the statement that, say, the 4th moment can be expressed as a polynomial in its 1st and 2nd moments. I have a vague recollection of this being related to the finiteness of the Weingarten coefficients, but correct me if I'm mistaken.

What I wanted to say is that the first and second paragraph are not equivalent. Thus, I took the freedom to answer the question I can :) Anyway, the other question about the dependency of the moments is indeed interesting and perhaps there's something buried in the Weingarten literature.This is not clear to me, and I couldn't find anything useful by looking in recent reviews (e.g. Collins 2022). I'll think about it. (for now I updated my answer for clarification)
